# are there any unordered basis,what is the most basic example???

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have been doing linear algebra and I can't really understand the existence of basis other than ordered basis ,but since ordered basis are taught as special arrangement basis then what are other types of basis

Comment: Unordered basis. This is the **set** of basis elements. So for example the sequence $v_1,v_2$, where $v_1=(1,0)$ and $v_2=(0,1)$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R^2}$. The **set** $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is an unordered basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *basis* $B$ of some vector space $V$ is a subset $B\subset V$ of vectors such that none of these vectors is a finite linear combination of other vectors in the set, and such that any vector $x\in V$ is a finite linear combination of vectors in $B$.

As soon as you want to do computations using such a basis the set $B$ has to be "organized" somehow, in most cases via some standard set $I$, like $[n]$, ${\mathbb N}$, etc., serving as index set, so that $B$ appears as a *family* $(b_\iota)_{\iota\in I}\>$. The index set does not have to be ordered, as in the following example: Let $P_n$ be the vector space of real polynomials in two variables $x$, $y$ of total degree $\leq n$. The monomials $x^k y^l$ with $k+l\leq n$ form a basis of $P_n$, but the set of these monomials can a priori be "organized" in various ways.

In the  case where $V$ is finite-dimensional a *basis* usually comes with a pre-assigned organization, and it is customary to count two bases consisting of the same vectors, but differently indexed, as different. In this sense the lists $(1,x,x^2,x^3, y, yx, yx^2, y^2, y^2 x, y^3)$ and $(1,x,y,x^2, xy, y^2, x^3, x^2y,xy^2, y^3)$ constitute different bases of $P_3$.